Why is the EMF zero in a conducting rod perpendicular to length
Consider a rod moving in uniform magnetic field with its length perpendicular to the field.
My textbook says EMF induced is zero in this case, but why won’t there be a transverse electric field across the rod and that electric field should also be considerable ??

There is an electromotive force (EMF) when a conducting rod goes through a uniform magnetic field with its length going against the field. Let's break this down:
EMF that moves:
It is called a motional EMF because it is caused by the rod.
It happens because the stick and the magnetic field are moving relative to each other.
EMF = LvB is the formula for motional EMF.
In this case, (L) stands for the rod's length.
(v) is the rod's speed in relation to the magnetic field.
(B) shows how strong the magnetic field is.
Which way the induced current is going:
How the induced current flows depends on which way the rod is moving and which way the magnetic field is facing.
We can find the direction of the created current by using the right-hand rule.
Following Lenz's law, the created magnetic field fights against the change in flux.
Why the EMF is not zero:
Since the stick is moving, the magnetic flux changes.
The rod moves through a different place even though it is not in the magnetic field.
An triggered EMF is caused by this change in flux.
There is a potential difference because the current is driven by the electric field across the rod.
Cross-Face Electric Field:
There will be an electric field across the rod, that much is true.
The moving charges inside the rod create the crosswise electric field.
However, (LvB) still gives the net EMF across the whole rod.
To sum up, the EMF is not zero because the magnetic flux is changing, and the transverse electric field inside the rod adds to the generated current. Both processes work together to keep energy from being lost.
For visual explanation watch the video in https://www.khanacademy.org/science/physics/magnetic-forces-and-magnetic-fields/magnetic-flux-faradays-law/v/emf-induced-in-rod-traveling-through-magnetic-field.
Sources:
khanacademy.org
physics.stackexchange.com
youtube.com
byjus.com
toppr.com
